# Does Objective-C have concepts of value/reference type like C#?

Tags: objective-c

According to the search on Google, looks like it doesn't officially have value/reference type. If it doesn't have, what's the counterparts? What's it called? Is it called 'Obj-C class and non Objc-C class' or 'static type and dynamic type'?

However, to me, a NSString object in obj-c 'works' like a reference type in C#. It'll lead to a compiling error "statically allocated instance of Objective-C class ..." if to define it without '*'

```
NSString * pstr = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Some native types, like NSInteger or C struct, which can be created without '*', can I say it 'works' like a value type in C#?

```
NSInteger i = 0;
```

Comment: In C++, objects can be divided to those created on stack and those on heap. Is there such a thing in Object-C?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All Objective-C objects are accessed by a pointer. In that sense they are all reference types.

Some Objective-C types define object equality (the -isEqual: method) as something other than pointer equality. These types behave as value-like types. Such types include NSString and NSNumber.

Types that are not Objective-C classes can be true value types in the C# sense.